# How to populate wxpython LIstCtrl with OnClick event

Tags: python-2.7, events, onclick, wxpython, listctrl

I want to design a wxpython ListCtrl. So when the Search button is clicked i am getting list like this

```
    [(7, u'GLUOCOSE', u'C6H1206'), (8, u'SUCROSE', u'C12H22O11')]
```

I want to populate the listctrl with the above output. I am InsertStringItem method, which will return me the index of current row and rest of the columns are filled by SetStringItem() method.But that gives me TypeError: String or Unicode type required.How do i accomplish this?

```
def OnSearch(self, event):        
    placeholder = '?'
    placeholders = ','.join(placeholder for unused in self.molecule_list)
    query = 'SELECT * FROM MOLECULE WHERE MOL_NUMBER IN (%s)' % placeholders
    cursor = self.conn.execute(query, self.molecule_list)
    final = cursor.fetchall()
    print final 
    for j in final: 
        index = self.list.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, j[0]) 
        self.list.SetStringItem(index, 1, j[1]) 
        self.list.SetStringItem(index, 2, j[2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over the cursor, rather than the data which was returned in the variable `final`. Swap over to iterate using `final`

```
index = 0
for j in final: 
    index = self.list.InsertStringItem(index, str(j[0])) 
    self.list.SetStringItem(index, 1, j[1]) 
    self.list.SetStringItem(index, 2, j[2])
    index +=1
```

The easiest way, is to ensure that the `ListCtrl` has a `style=wx.LC_REPORT` and then use `Append`.

```
for j in final:
    self.list.Append((j[0],j[1],j[2],j[3]))
```

Where j[n] is each item you require from the data for the number of items in the `ListCtrl`. I hope that makes sense.

Here is an example showing both methods

```
import wx
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Molecules")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.index = 0
        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(-1,100),
                         style=wx.LC_REPORT
                         )
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Number')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Element')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Make up')

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Add data")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_lines)
        btn2 = wx.Button(panel, label="Append data")
        btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.app_lines)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def add_lines(self, event):
        data = [[7, 'GLUCOSE', 'C6H1206'],[8,'SUCROSE', 'C12H22O11']]
        index = 0
        for j in data:
            self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(index, str(j[0]))
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 1, j[1])
            self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(index, 2, j[2])
            index += 1
    def app_lines(self, event):
        data = [[7, 'GLUCOSE', 'C6H1206'],[8,'SUCROSE', 'C12H22O11']]
        for j in data:
            self.list_ctrl.Append((j[0],j[1],j[2]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I got the answer but when i try this using InsertStringItem that gives me TypeError: String or Unicode type required.
and i am inserting a string

Comment: Without being able to see the error or the listctrl it's difficult to say but the structure should be `InsertStringItem(index, label, imageIndex=-1)`. Using `sys.maxint` for every `index` is very WRONG. Try the `append` method, it's easier.

Comment: For the index, initialise it before the loop to zero and increment within the loop. That gives you a fighting chance of that code working.

Comment: Thanks are appreciated, perhaps an accept or vote up of the answer is appropriate